# jQuery livesearch and rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, livesearch

I'm trying to implement some live search function on my index view. I found this plugin http://www.mikemerritt.me/blog/livefilter-1-3-jquery-plugin/ but can't adapt to rails. I'm trying to reproduce the demo but can't make it work. can someone explain how to adapt the demo to rails (3.1) environment. Thanks

Comment: 14% rate on 10 question. Please accept other answer from your previous questions.

Comment: Managed to get it working with this script https://github.com/nakajima/jquery-livesearch

Answer (score 0):

you could also use jQuery-UIs [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). there are a ton of questions / tutorials and i think even gems to feed this autocomplete from a rails backend.

Comment: yeah but what I want I want is the filter as you type in. I also need a rails specific example to get started. Thanks though

Comment: ok, so you're pre-rendering the list and you don't need any live data from your backend? its pure live-filtering? in this case, this doesn't even concern rails, it's pure javascript, and you can pretty much copy&paste the demo code. do you need help with setup (i.e. getting the plugin in your asset pipeline)?